# word wraped tex on Android canvas

Tags: android, text, canvas, word-wrap

I'm trying to write some strings to a canvas (live wallpaper) however long string don't get word-wraped is there any way to do it? 
I think canvas is the only thing I can use for this, since it's a live wallpaper.

Comment: god, that cant be easy, any examples to share?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to do your own word wrapping.

Check out android.text.Layout and its subclasses android.text.StaticLayout and android.text.DynamicLayout

something like this:

```
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, txtpaint, textW,Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.3f, 0, false);
txtcanvas.translate(xoffs, yoffs); //position the text
layout.draw(txtcanvas);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work - from the documentation: DynamicLayout is a text layout that updates itself as the text is edited.

This is used by widgets to control text layout. You should not need to use this class directly unless you are implementing your own widget or custom display object, or need to call Canvas.drawText() directly.
If this is the case, then this won't work since you need to call Canvas.drawText() when using canvas...

Comment: It will work. Implementing your own custom widget is exactly what this question is about. layout.draw will probably call Canvas.drawText for you after doing the formatting. Note that you send in the canvas to the draw call.

Comment: Olof, I know that SO comments are not for +1s or thumbs up, but many thanks for your answer, saved me hours of searching for the right tool. To everyone else, yes, this does work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but for these situations I really like to simply create a View, layout it, and then write a "screenshot" of it into a Bitmap.

This function will create a bitmap from the params + the xml layout in "just_a_textview".

```
private static Bitmap renderTextIntoBitmap(Context context, Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig, String text, int textColor, int maxTextWidth) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    TextView tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.just_a_textview, null);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setMaxWidth(maxTextWidth);

    int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxTextWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    tv.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    tv.layout(0, 0, tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredHeight());
    tv.setTextColor(textColor);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getWidth(), tv.getHeight(), bitmapConfig);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    tv.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

You don't want to do this in every frame, but once you have the bitmap, drawing it on a canvas is very fast. And this gives you all the flexibility of ANY Android View.

I understand that this won't work if your text is very dynamic, but you can maybe do it like this and use the canvas matrix to do any scaling/rotation that you might want to do. 
This can be further optimized for performance obviously, e.g. by pulling out the layout inflation.